# Too many antennas around a single energy transmitting antenna?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, power

I am not a physicist. So I am not even sure, if I am phrasing this question properly. Lets say there is a wireless transmitter transmitting energy. Let us say I place $N$ number of antennas around it such that each antenna has a capacitor attached to it which can store energy. Does the energy received at a particular antenna is influenced by the total number of receiving antennas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is!

When the electromagnetic wave reaches an antenna, electrons in the antenna will be accelerated and there will be a current. This current creates a secondary electromagnetic wave, which travels in all directions. It will certainly hit other antennas in the vicinity. So, the signal obtained by each antenna will vary dependent on the surroundings.

**EDIT**
To answer your question in the comment:

> Ok. Let us assume I have a way of stopping this secondary em wave. If
>   I have a infinite number of antennas in a circle around this
>   transmitter. what will happen?

To reduce the secondary EM-wave, you have two options: either shield the antenna, or take a very bad antenna (such that there is less current). The second case is obviously not good, because less current means less energy intake, which is of course what you are aiming for. The first method will only work both ways: the primary EM-wave, which is supposed to induce a current, will be attenuated by the shield and the induced current will decrease.

Comment: Ok. Let us assume I have a way of stopping this secondary em wave. If I have a infinite number of antennas in a circle around this transmitter. what will happen? Will the antennas get a bit of energy each. Sorry for the flurry of questions.

Comment: Seems to me you would be making a Faraday cage around the transmitter.

Comment: @JonCuster But isn't it a circle unlike a sphere. How does the faraday cage effect come in that case?